# Code = 3504: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group. Output directed to answer set tab

Tags: teradata

This code won't produce an output due to this error:  3706: Syntax error: expected something between the 'DESC' keyword and the 'LIMIT' keyword.

I just don't know what to do.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Member_Dimension.Member_Key AS "Top 5 Members", 
   SUM(Total_Scan_Amount) As "Total Scan Amount"
FROM Item_Scan_Fact, Member_Dimension, Date_Dimension
WHERE Item_Scan_Fact.Member_Key = Member_Dimension.Member_Key
  AND Item_Scan_Fact.Transaction_Date_Key = Date_Dimension.Date_Key
  AND Date_Dimension.Year_Number = 2000
ORDER BY "Total Scan Amount" DESC;
```

I need to answer this question: List the top 5 shoppers (number) who spent the most on Martin Luther King Jr. Day in 2000. (Hint: Use SELECT TOP 5….)

Comment: The hint has the hint for what to do instead of `LIMIT`

Comment: I tried using TOP 5 but I can't get it to work. Can you show me how?

Comment: What was the query you did with `TOP` and what error did you get? Please edit that into the question

Comment: just edited! Thank you!

Comment: Also, do you want a screenshot of the tables and relationships?

Comment: You need to

    `GROUP BY Member_Dimension.Member_Key`